# When is it appropriate to repost a question?

Tags: support, unanswered-questions

I have a question [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/98578/129767%20here) that hasn't received any answers in a while. Is it appropriate to repost the question so it receives some more attention?

Comment: Short answer: Never. It will simply be closed as a duplicate of the original.

Comment: Further: It's possible that no one here knows the answer. Have you spread the question around to get it a wider audience? Have you continued to do the research yourself? Maybe you'll find the answer after all.

Comment: @AʟE. I have been continuing my research, but have not found anything. And I don't know anyone who can answer this question

Comment: @vikarjramun : I posted an answer to the [question](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/98578/129767%20here) on the main site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers

> ## What should I do if no one answers my question?
>
> First, make sure you’ve [asked a good question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask). To get better
> answers, you may need to put additional effort into your question.
> Edit your question to provide status and progress updates. Document
> your own continued efforts to answer your question. This will
> naturally bump your question to the homepage and get more people
> interested in it.
>
> If, despite your best efforts, you feel questions aren’t getting good
> answers, you can help by [offering a bounty](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/bounty) on any question more
> than two days old.

Comment: I have 18 rep so I can not award a bounty

Comment: Check the first paragraph. Another related post, [How do I write a great question?](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3857/how-do-i-write-a-great-question)